# Xamarin Forms Image Recognition

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, image-recognition, emgucv

I would like to know if there is any recognition system for Xamarin Forms that can recognise a point (for example a green filled circle) with the camera, in order to extract info from that point (like coordinates).

I know that EmguCV maybe can do that, but the samples are not working and if you want to use it on Xamarin Forms, you have to pay a commercial license, what does not make sense to me if I can't test it before.

Any info about this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should be able to use the openCV libraries directly but its going to be painful. IF this is a critical path you might want to just write it yourself. Id recommend writing it in C for speed reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see 3 ways for you:

- **use EmguCV:** 
  I use EmguCV for Xamarin Forms, and it's working pretty well.
  But it's pretty complicated to configure it... Try this tutorial: [Using Emgu with Xamarin Forms](https://kampeki-factory.blogspot.com/2017/12/emgu-with-xamarin-forms-guide-part-1.html). I think you can test it without buying a licence but only on a simulator...
- I also found an **Azure service called "Custom Vision"**. You can train a neural network? to recognize objects on your pictures... Take a look at here (there is a free plan): [Custom vision Azure service](https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/pricing/details/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/)
- Finally, If you have enough **skill in image processing** you can do it by yourself (there are many tutorial on the web).

==> For me the first solution is the best (Emgu is really powerfull). So if you plan to use it for several projects, I suggest you to buy a licence...
"Custom Vision" Azure service look really convenient but I don't know if it fit your needs... You have to test it, and the free plan is limited too...

Good luck

Comment: Thank you KFactory! I'm trying to implement EmguCV, I found that tutorial but it's only for Shared Project. Do you think I can implement it on Net Standard project? If so, any tips?
I will also take a loot at Azure. Maybe it's a good choice :)

Comment: There is no "Xamarin Forms" EmguCV lib... There are only native Xamarin iOS & Android libs, that's why you have to use shared projects... It's not really convenient but for small/medium projects, it's ok. I think there is no NET Standard implementation actually... The hardest is to start with this library :) !

Comment: Thank you man! that's very useful information! many people will be glad to read that :) Cheers!

Comment: Hi, Is it possible to use Net Standard instead of Shared Project in your EmguCV tutorial?